# How to open file upload prompt when text link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works in FF6 and IE 7, 8 and 9, but not Chrome/Safari or Opera:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $('#uploadFile').click(function(e) {
                $('#fileUploadField').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        });
    </script>

    <input type="file" name="something" style="display: none" id="fileUploadField" />
    <a href="" id="uploadFile">Upload File</a>
```

I'm guessing this is due to browser security restrictions. Does anyone know of any cross browser solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't invoke click on a hidden element, it's a security restriction. Instead of `display: none`, use `opacity: 0` instead. That seems to work.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/S2hRP/). I see the file selection dialog with FF6 on Win 7, Chrome 13 on Win 7/Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Safari 5 on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Comment: Awsome, didn't know about the not being allowed to invoke click on hidden rule. Instead of opacity I used: visibility:hidden; position:absolute; since opcity is a css3 property and as such isn't supported in < IE9. This doesn't work in Opera however which is a minor bummer.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there is no "display:none" it won't work in IE8. As soon as you click submit, IE8 will delete the data in the file-input field and doesn't submit the form. Try following code as php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IE8-Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#btn').live('click', function(){
        $('#file').click();
      })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input id="file" type="file" name="image" class="image"/>
      <div id="btn">Click me to do a js click on the input type=file button.</div>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" name="formsubmit" value="Upload"/>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['formsubmit'])){
        echo '<div>POST-Data</div>';
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($_POST);
        var_dump($_FILES);
        echo '</pre>';
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```